# Program not giving the expected result

Tags: python

I'm currently following an intro to cs course in python. The code is given below.

```
school = 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology'
numVowels = 0
numCons = 0

for char in school:
    if char == 'a' or char == 'e' or char == 'i' \
    or char == 'o' or char == 'u':
        numVowels += 1
    elif char == 'o' or char == 'M':
        print(char)
    else:
        numCons -= 1

print('numVowels is: ' + str(numVowels))
print('numCons is: ' + str(numCons))
```

According to my observation:

```
numVowels = 12
numCons = -23
```

The interpreter says:

```
numVowels = 11
numCons = -25
```

This is a question I got from an edx course. I'm trying to solve this.

Comment: M**a**ss**a**ch**u**s**e**tts Inst**i**t**u**t**e** **o**f T**e**chn**o**l**o**gy, there are 11 vowels according to your if; your only counting the lowercase characters.

Comment: The program does not count capital vowels (e.g. **I**) as vowels.

Comment: The given code is pretty horrible Python.

Comment: `elif char == 'o'` would never get triggered here :)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the next lesson is "Okay let's look at this code and figure out what's wrong with it." I also wouldn't be surprised if the code is help as a sterling example of Proper Python Code by the instructor. Nothing surprises me anymore.

Comment: This question's title is not okay. Please make it describe the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems to be case sensitive. A quick fix would be

```
school = 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology'
numVowels = 0
numCons = 0

for char in school.lower():
    if char in "aeiou":
        numVowels += 1
    elif char in "om":
        print(char)
    else:
        numCons -= 1

print('numVowels is: ' + str(numVowels))
print('numCons is: ' + str(numCons))
```

resulting in

```
m
numVowels is: 12
numCons is: -24
```

Though note that your code isn't counting consonants, just characters that aren't vowels or m.

Maybe consider the following instead:

```
import string
school = 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology'
numVowels = 0
numCons = 0

for char in school.lower():
    if char in "aeiou":
        numVowels += 1
    elif char in string.ascii_letters:
        numCons += 1
```

Though it really depends what you're trying to do with your resulting numVowels and numCons variables. Without an explict expected output, it's tough to say.

Comment: Explanation: `school.lower()` makes case-insensitive comparison possible.